# Spring Scheduled Task, strange behavior

Tags: spring

I have a Scheduled task which runs every 800 seconds from a server towards its clients to see if they are online. If they are not, it will send me an email, and will send an email when they are back online.

So, this is the scheduled task

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 800000)
    public void pingAllClients() {
        logger.debug("Schedule pingClients");
        List<Client> clients = clientService.findAllClients();

        Iterator<Client> it = clients.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Client client = it.next();
            String ip = client.getCurrentIp();
            int idClient = client.getIdClient();
            boolean isOnline = client.isOnline();
            try {
                boolean reachable = reachClient.isReachable(ip);
                if (reachable) {
                    if (!isOnline) {
                        logger.debug("Client " + idClient + " back online");
                        client.setOnline(true);
                        clientService.updateClient(client);
                        smtp.sendEmail(serverName, ip, true);
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Client " + idClient + " not available");
                    if (isOnline) {
                        client.setOnline(false);
                        clientService.updateClient(client);
                        smtp.sendEmail(serverName, ip, false);

                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Errore", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

reachClient.isReachable(ip) is this method:

```
public boolean isReachable(String ip){

        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 22), 50*1000);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, it should be: every 800 seconds i loop my clients, see if the are reachable or not, and if they change status, i will receive an email. In the email i print the date/time of the request.

It always happens that i get an email from an offline client and soon after (2-10 seconds) an email it is back online, as, for the same client, i'm getting 2 emails in a single iteration, how is it possibile? Each client should be reachable or not for every loop, not both...

The last 2 emails I got are (6 seconds delay)

*Client 192.168.42.13 is offline - Date: 11-12-2016 17:14:30*

*Client 192.168.42.13 back online - Date: 11-12-2016 17:14:36*

Comment: Are you confident in the contents of your List of clients? Id check exactly what findAllClients returns. The logic also reads a little funny to me, if the client is reachable and not online you are declaring them online.

Comment: the client list is correct. The logic is to avoid to receive multiple email if a client goes down. So the first time it goes offline, i set it offline in the DB and send an email. Next step, if it continues to be offline, no email will be sent. I will get an email only when it is reachable again.